# determine exponent or subscript by position via Y axis for a math equation in kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs, superscript, exponent

can someone please help write a function in KineticJS to determine math object position. I.e. determine if a number 2 is the squared index or just a 2. the positions of the objects are taken using the x-axis (horizontal position with 0 furthest to the left). The functions will then be written out in order e.g:
[f’(x)][=][2][x][2]
Then check for the position via the y-axis. If a function is notably higher or lower then it is considered an exponent (for above) or a subscript label (for below). We then have:
[f’(x)][=][2][x][?squared?]
If any function is notably smaller, it will assume either an exponent or subscript label. and ask a user to confirm the function is
[f’(x)][=][2][x][squared]

Answer (score 0):

I doubt many people will want to take their time to do your work for you, however what you are trying to accomplish shouldn't be too difficult.  You will need to use `getAttr('y')` on the base number and then the same call on the subscript and compare those two values.  The function can return a boolean that returns true if its an exponent and false is its a subscript?  There are many different directions you can go with this.